# A simple meteor template and routing does not work

Tags: meteor

I am a beginner trying to get around things with meteor.

I have a program written in meteor which does not render the templates completely.

The main.html file contain the template definitions as below.

```html
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>


<template name='ApplicationLayout'>
  <header>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </header>

  <aside>
    {{> yield "postAside"}}
  </aside>

  <article>
    {{> yield "main"}}  
  </article>

  <hr />

  <footer>
    {{> yield "postFooter"}}
  </footer>
</template>

<template name='post'>
  <p>Hello!!! This is Main Post Template.</p>
</template>

<template name='postAside'>
  <p>Side Menu</p>
</template>

<template name='postFooter'>
  <p>This is the footer.</p>
</template>
```

The routes file contains the below code.

```js
Router.route('/', function() {
 this.layout('ApplicationLayout');

 this.render('post', {to: 'main'});

 this.render('postAside', {to: 'aside'});

 this.render('postFooter', {to: 'footer'});
});
```

This is what renders in the browser. What you see in the browser is that only the post template is rendered and not the aside and footer templates.

[View the Actual Result Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDbnu.png)

[View Expected Result Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFRd.png)

When I use {{#contentFor }} directive, then the result is as expected but as in above code, the result is as shown in actual result.

Can anyone help me to find what is going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the route as below:

```
Router.map(function () {
this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'post',
    layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'postAside': {to: 'aside'},
        'postFooter': {to: 'footer'}
    }
});
```

Change the html to have the below

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>


<template name='ApplicationLayout'>
  <header>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </header>

  <aside>
    {{> yield region='aside'}}
   </aside>

  <article>
    {{> yield "main"}}  
  </article>

  <hr />

  <footer>
    {{> yield region='footer'}}
  </footer>
</template>

<template name='post'>
  <p>Hello!!! This is Main Post Template.</p>
</template>

<template name='postAside'>
  <p>Side Menu</p>
</template>

<template name='postFooter'>
  <p>This is the footer.</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. But. I just identified the problem in my original code.

The problem is with the html file where I gave the wrong name for the regions.

The code snippet should have been like this.

  <aside>
    {{> yield "aside"}}
  </aside>

  <article>
    {{> yield "main"}}  
  </article>

  <hr />

  <footer>
    {{> yield "footer"}}
  </footer>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This works perfectly. But. I just identified the problem in my original code.

The problem is with the html file where I gave the wrong name for the regions.

The code snippet should have been like this.

```
<aside>
  {{> yield "aside"}}
</aside>

<article>
  {{> yield "main"}}  
</article>

<hr />

<footer>
  {{> yield "footer"}}
</footer>
```